# Local HTML and JavaScript in Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, css, swift, webkit

As part of an iOS application I'm developing, I need to load some local HTML and JS files. Since Swift 4 is relatively new and Apple's documentation isn't the best, I haven't been able to get everything working so far.

This is how I have been loading the HTML:

```
class LaundryRoomController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!;
    var room: Room!;

    override func loadView () {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration();
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration);
        webView.uiDelegate = self;
        view = webView;
    }

    override func viewDidLoad () {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        let html = self.readHTML(path: "laundry-webview/index");
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil);
    }
...
}
```

Where `readHTML(path: String)` is a method of the same class. My folder structure for the application looks like this:

```
project/
|
|---- Tools/
|---- Data/
|---- Controllers/
      |---- controller files
      |---- laundry-webview/
            |---- HTML, JS, and CSS files
|...
```

The HTML view I'm loading is javascript-heavy; there's no actual content in the `<body>` of the HTML file, it just loads javascript libraries, files, and some CSS. As of now, none of the javascript seems to be running, or at least running correctly. It may be worthy to note that I am loading the external JS libraries from a CDN rather than locally.

How can I get this WebView to correctly load and run my local files?

Comment: Have you tried debugging in the Simulator?

Comment: @MikeTaverne Yes. I don't believe it's the actual Webkit WebView, but I don't know if any of the JS libraries/files are loading correctly. I could try to debug in the JS itself, but that seems a bit cumbersome.